# Close vote queue continues to show as active after running out of close votes

Tags: bug

I believe there is a bug in the review queue:

When I go to the close votes queue, and I've used up my close votes for the day, it should not show that there are close votes for me to review.

Rather, it should grey out just like first posts or others do when you've hit your daily max.

It's especially annoying when you're in the middle of reviewing a post, and you go to click on close, and you get the little pop-up saying you've used them up.

And, before I'm accused of being obsessive about close voting, I'm just running through the queue.  You can *easily* use up all of your votes for the day that way.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I agree; this happens to me as well. It doesn't happen every time, though. More episodic in nature. I don't mind admitting I have run out of close votes. When there are 30+ in the queue, it happens.